# My mouse fell to the floor

Tags: mouse

My mouse fell down the table, but it can still be used.

However, when I drag / move the mouse, it's sensitivity seems to be not so good, and I cannot move to a place very accurately.

I guess nothing broke, but the cover of the battery box fell out.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Buy a new mouse. It's very unlikely that you'll find it worthwhile to fix the physical damage you have caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is in your tracking, i guess here we have some probabilities :

- The batteries are dead : please verify your batteries state, or change them completely and see if the problem is fixed.
- The optical sensor is full of dirt or dust : feel free to clean out the sensor with your mouth blow if not with a blow dryer
- If it is not the case i recommend to verify the batteries connectors inside the batteries dwell maybe they are slipped out.

Comment: I guess just the lazer (optical sensor??).